# Working of mmap()

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, mmap, virtual-memory

I am trying to get an idea on how does memory mapping take place using the system call mmap.

So far I know mmap takes arguments from the user and returns a logical address of where the file is stored. When the user tries to access it takes this address to the map table converts it to a a physical address and carries the operation as requested.

However I found articles as [code example](https://jlmedina123.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/mmap-driver-implementation/) and [Theoretical explanation](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1)

What it mentions is the memory mapping is carried out as:

A. Using system call `mmap ()`

B. file operations using `(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)`
What I am trying to figure out is:

1. How the arguments passed in the `mmap` system call are used in the `struct vm_area_struct *vma)` More generally how are these 2 related.
   for instance: the struct vm_area_struct has arguments such as starting address, ending address permissions,etc. How are the values sent by the user used to fill values of these variables.
2. I am trying to write a driver so, Does the kernal fill the values for variables in the structure for us and I simply use it to call and pass values to remap_pfn_range
3. And a more fundamental question, why is a different file systems operation needed. The fact that mmap returns the virtual address means that it has already achieved a mapping doesnt it ?

Finally I am not that clear about how the entire process would work in user as well as kernal space. Any documentation explaining the process in details would be helpful.

Comment: Too many questions. And requesting documentation is off-topic here. Please, be more specific. E.g. - `The fact that 'mmap' returns the virtual address means that it has already achieved a mapping doesn't it?` - No, upon return this virtual address could be non-usable. Accessing it cause page fault, which triggers call to driver's `mmap_fault` function. This function should map virtual page caused page fault to physical address.

Comment: I too am confused as to what you are asking. One of the problems is that mmap is a poorly designed system service that does multiple things depending upon the parameters passed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok I will not ask for documentation. To make the question more specific, I am tring to figure out how to use `struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma` when dealing with memory mapping and what values to retrieve when trying to map page tables